# Create a view using latest address record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a view that joins two tables and returns the relevant address details as of a particular date.

I have two tables:

**Employee:**

```
ID (Primary key)
Name
```

**EmployeeAddress:**

```
ID (PK), (FK to Employee.ID)
DateValidFrom (PK)
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
PostCode
```

How do I join the two together to get the employee details and the address as of a certain date?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for example using outer apply:

```
select
  E.ID,
  E.Name,
  A.AddressLine1,
  A.AddressLine2,
  A.PostCode
from
  Employee E
  outer apply (
    select top 1
      A.AddressLine1,
      A.AddressLine2,
      A.PostCode
    from
      EmployeeAddress A
    where
      A.ID = E.ID and
      A.DateValidFrom < getdate()
    order by
      A.DateValidFrom desc
  ) A
```

Comment: Oops, wrong alias. There's no need for additional joins, this is enough

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a query that finds the latest datevalidfrom for each id and use that as a derived table that you join the other tables with, something like this:

```
select * from employee e
join employeeaddress ea on e.id = ea.id
join (select id, max(datevalidfrom) as max_date from employeeaddress group by id) ea2
  on ea.id = ea2.id and ea.datevalidfrom = ea2.max_date
```

By joining with the max(datevalidfrom) in the derived table you limit the rest of the query (that would get you all rows) to the very latest.

And to turn it into a view:

```
create view employee_latest_address as
select e.id, e.name, ea.datevalidfrom, ea.addressline1, ea.addressline2, ea.postcode 
from employee e
join employeeaddress ea on e.id = ea.id
join (select id, max(datevalidfrom) max_date from employeeaddress group by id) ea2
  on ea.id = ea2.id and ea.datevalidfrom = ea2.max_date
```